# Alternative to using Indirect

Tags: excel

I have a large workbook of data sheets, all representing the same thing as it changes over time. Each tab representing a different snapshot.

I then want to be able to compare these in a final sheet, by using drop downs to select the relevant versions.

Currently I am using the Indirect function to do the delta calculations based on the selected sheets.

I have spent some time attempting to come up with an alternative method which does not use the Indirect function.

Any ideas?

(I have also been attempting to avoid macros)

Comment: What is the problem with indirect?

Comment: Not 'best practice' as it is hard to follow and has been flagged during verification. Hence why I have also been avoiding macros as they to are deemed 'not best practice'

Comment: If they're going to be that stringent on best practices then I would make the comment that the type of analysis you're looking to do shouldn't be in Excel at all.